# Can I pass the whole model through a GNN but then only choose a mini-batch for the loss?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, graph-neural-network

I am training an unsupervised GNN model on a set of node features with a triplet loss function.

I was wondering if it is correct for every mini batch to pass all the nodes (not only the mini batch) and then perform the triplet loss on the mini batch:

```
       for step, (anchors, 
                anchors_episodes, 
                anchors_sampled_episode_ids, 
                positives, 
                negatives) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader, desc="Training", leave=False)):
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            z = model(dataset.x, dataset.edge_index)
            z_anchors = z[anchors]
            z_positives = z[positives]
            z_negatives = z[negatives]
            
            loss = criterion(z_anchors, z_positives, z_negatives)        
            losses.append(loss)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

By doing this i avoid sampling from the mini batch to create a new edge_index.

I have tried training the models like this but the results are worse than expected and I am wondering if the training loop is at fault. I haven't seen people doing this anywhere (they pass in the model() the mini-batch nodes only, and modify accordingly the edge_index) so I was wondering if there is a particular reason for that. My graph is pretty small (12k nodes) so it's not that cumbersome in terms of memory.